# How can i install SMB Client on Openshift Gear

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge, libsmbclient

How can i install SMB Client on Openshift Gear

Actually i have successfully installed `OwnCloud` Using https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/4-owncloud
but the only problem is after installing the `External storage support` plugin it gives me hard warning `Note: "smbclient" is not installed. Mounting of SMB / CIFS, SMB / CIFS using OC login is not possible. Please ask your system administrator to install it.` so it clearly suggest that i need to install smbclient on the server which i cant install as i don't have sufficent privilage on server.

Can anybody help? Any cartrigde or any way to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

SMB is not enabled for users to use on OpenShift online, and you are correct that users do not have the required permissions to install it.  unfortunately there is really no way around this.  If you need to use SMB Client, you really need your own Virtual Machine that you have root access to to install whatever software you need.

Comment: yes you are right but they should install on user request or any work around should be there because most of the software would require some or the other components to work. this way they fail to provide flexibility to their customers